# QuickFIX/J - SendingTime accuracy issue

Tags: fix-protocol, quickfixj

I am unable to resolve the error below.

```
toAdmin: Message=8=FIXT.1.1|9=151|**35=3**|34=510|49=BETA_1|52=20240229-12:47:30.600|56=Beta_2|129=BRIDGE|45=540|**58=SendingTime accuracy problem**|371=52|372=8|373=10|10=003|
toAdmin: Message=8=FIXT.1.1|9=113|**35=5**|34=511|49=BETA_1|52=20240229-12:47:30.600|56=Beta_2|**58=SendingTime accuracy problem, field=52**|10=160|
toAdmin: Message=8=FIXT.1.1|9=151|**35=3**|34=512|49=BETA_1|52=20240229-12:47:30.600|56=Beta_2|129=BRIDGE|45=541|**58=SendingTime accuracy problem**|371=52|372=8|373=10|10=006|
toAdmin: Message=8=FIXT.1.1|9=113|35=5|34=513|49=BETA_1|52=20240229-12:47:30.601|56=Beta_2|58=SendingTime accuracy problem, field=52|10=163|
toAdmin: Message=8=FIXT.1.1|9=151|35=3|34=514|49=BETA_1|52=20240229-12:47:30.601|56=Beta_2|129=BRIDGE|45=542|58=SendingTime accuracy problem|371=52|372=8|373=10|10=010|
toAdmin: Message=8=FIXT.1.1|9=113|35=5|34=515|49=BETA_1|52=20240229-12:47:30.601|56=Beta_2|58=SendingTime accuracy problem, field=52|10=165|
toAdmin: Message=8=FIXT.1.1|9=151|35=3|34=516|49=BETA_1|52=20240229-12:47:30.601|56=Beta_2|129=BRIDGE|45=543|58=SendingTime accuracy problem|371=52|372=8|373=10|10=013|
toAdmin: Message=8=FIXT.1.1|9=113|35=5|34=517|49=BETA_1|52=20240229-12:47:30.601|56=Beta_2|58=SendingTime accuracy problem, field=52|10=167|
fromAdmin: Message=8=FIXT.1.1|9=71|35=0|34=544|49=Beta_2|52=20240229-12:45:48.269|56=BETA_1|10=020|
```

I can't find anything on internet that can help.

I already verified both solutions below, but it'sn't the source of the problem :

- Verify system clocks on both sides are in sync and that SendingTime(52) is current time.
- Note: OrigSendingTime(122) should be earlier than SendingTime(52) unless the message is being resent within the same second during which it was sent.

I don't think I need to add CheckLatency for my case since I get this error only few times.

If you have any suggestion, I will be very open to try it.

Comment: You aren't setting these values manually, are you?  (Also: don't look at your app-level println logs: those aren't reliable.  Look at the message log created by your LogFactory.)

Comment: You can clearly see from your log output that you have a problem with time sync. The message that you receive in the last line is about two minutes before the messages you send earlier.

Comment: Thanks guys for your response!
@Grant I retrieve my data from an excel sheet, but the time (tag 11) is generated automatically. And regarding my LogFactory, I do have the same information I posted here.

Comment: @John, I did see the time lag difference, but still don't know why ? neither how to correct that problem. Do you have any suggestion ?

Comment: Are you seeing this problem on specific messages? Normally I would generate a thread dump to see if something is hanging.

Comment: The issue comes randomly, some days I have it, others, no. I also can't debug from my local machine because my code is running on a server

Comment: Put code in your admin and app message callbacks that takes a thread dump. Next time it happens you should have an indication where it is hanging. I strongly assume it is hanging somewhere in your code, e.g. data base call or the like.